# function.array-diff problems!

Tags: php, arrays

im currently getting these error on my site:

```
Warning: array_keys() [function.array-keys]: The first argument should be an array on line 43

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 44

Warning: array_diff() [function.array-diff]: Argument #1 is not an array on line 47

Warning: array_diff() [function.array-diff]: Argument #1 is not an array on line 48
```

And the source are:

```
42.        $tmp = $this->network->get_user_follows($this->user->id);
43.     $tmp    = array_keys($tmp->followers);
44.     foreach($tmp as &$v) { $v = intval($v); }
45.     $tmp2   = array_keys($this->network->get_group_members($g->id));
46.     foreach($tmp2 as &$v) { $v = intval($v); }
47.     $tmp    = array_diff($tmp, $tmp2);
48.     $tmp    = array_diff($tmp, array(intval($this->user->id)));
```

Here is the var_dump output:

```
bool(false) array(1) { [2]=> int(3) }
```

I want to know what is the problem and how i fix it. Thanks!

Comment: $this->network->get_user_follows($this->user->id) is not returning an array. What is var_dump($tmp)? Something gone wrong in the method call and it is likely returning a value to represent an error. We will have to know var_dump($this->user->id) and the code to $this->network->get_user_follows to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions aren't returning arrays.  On the assumption they return arrays when there's data to be had, and some sort of empty (null or false) value otherwise, a simple cast may work:

```
$tmp    = $this->network->get_user_follows($this->user->id);
$tmp    = isset($tmp->followers) && is_array($tmp->followers) ? array_keys($tmp->followers) : array();
foreach($tmp as &$v) { $v = intval($v); }
$tmp2   = array_keys((array)$this->network->get_group_members($g->id));
foreach($tmp2 as &$v) { $v = intval($v); }
$tmp    = array_diff($tmp, $tmp2);
$tmp    = array_diff($tmp, array(intval($this->user->id)));
```

But even better, do this as a diagnostic:

```
var_dump($this->network->get_user_follows($this->user->id), $this->network->get_group_members($g->id));
```

This should make it a lot more clear what's actually going on

Comment: im getting bool(false) array(1) { [2]=> int(3) }  as result

any suggestion?

Comment: This is wrong.  You cannot call `$tmp->followers` if `$tmp` is an array.  `$tmp` must be an object.  There's some horrible variable reassignment with conflicting types going on in the original code.

Comment: Good call, d11wtq.  Updated with more appropriate code.  That was sloppy of me.

Answer (score 0):

`get_user_follows` is not supposed to return an array, it's supposed to return an object which has a property called `followers`.  It's the `followers` property that's not an array, and that's actually because `$tmp` is `FALSE` when it should be said object.

The code in `get_user_follows` has some guard clause that is making it return `FALSE` under some condition.  Figure out why and correct that ;)